# Elasticsearch bool query

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

In elasticsearch, I want to do a logical query like this:

Suppose A, B, C, and D are logical conditions ("match" conditions). I want an elasticsearch query with the equivalent of this SQL query:

```
(A OR B OR C) AND D
```

And I want to weigh the importance of A,B and C with `boost`

How do I structure the JSON for this query?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bool` query and `boost` option.

As you said to perform `OR` operation among the fields A,B & C you need to use `should` query with `minimum_should_match` as 1 (Default value) get [read more about miminum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html#query-dsl-minimum-should-match). you can add `boost` also init.

**Note:** For example I used term query, you need to use a appropriate query to get best results as per your requirement.

```
   {
        "should": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "A": "searchTerm"
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "B": "searchTerm"
                }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "C": "searchTerm"
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1,
        "boost": 1
    }
```

And to perform the `AND` operation between the above query and another field you need to add this with `must` query, finally the bool query will be like as below

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "D": "searchTerm"
                }
            },
            {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "A": "searchText"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "B": "searchText"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "C": "searchText"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "minimum_should_match": 1,
                "boost": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This will perform the logical operation what you have mentioned in the question **(A || B || C) && D**.

References:

- [Term query with boosting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query)

Comment: There's an error inside your latest example. The {} shouldn't be around the "should" block.

Answer (score -3):

Please go through [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).